# Batch file output to a new file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am working with a few csv files that I need to output to another file using a Windows Batch file. 
The batch file contents is below:
'@echo off
'(for /F "delims=," %%A in (input1.csv) do echo %%A) > output1.csv

Is there a way to execute the batch file to apply to a group of .csv files all located in the same folder?  Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%x in (*.csv) do (
    type nul>"%%~nx.new"
    for /F "usebackqdelims=," %%A in ("%%~x") do (echo(%%A)>> "%%~nx.new"
)
```

Comment: thanks for the info, it didn't work as expected.  I ran that updated batch file. It did create the files with .new extension.  I renamed the .csv and what I get is an output of the original file name, not the info that was in the data that was contained in the .csv file.

Comment: that works! fantastic.  Is there any way to also remove the first record as well?

Comment: @user1804387 add **skip=1** to the for loop:  _for /F "skip=1 usebackqdelims=," %%A_